# HTML / CSS - Place div's next and under each others

Tags: css, html

I have a problem and I hope someone can help me. What I want is this:

```
[lorem] [lorem
         ipsum
[other]  bla
         bla]
```

So this are 3 div's which are next and under each other, what I have is this:

```
[lorem] [lorem
         ipsum
         bla
         bla]

[other]
```

So when the div has ended the other div comes under the div's in stead of next to the div.

My code:

```
<div> Lorem </div>
<div> lorem ipsum bla bla </div>
<div> other </div>

div { float: left; }
```

Is this possible? Thanks!

Comment: Can you use one more div as a container for the left two divs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U might want this...

```
<div class="abc">
    <div> Lorem </div>
    <div> other </div>
</div>
<div class="abc"> lorem ipsum bla bla </div>


.abc { float: left; margin-right:20px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, you want all three divs to be inline in a row.
If thats what you want, then you should give width to your divs too.

for example if your parent container is 600px wide, then your floating divs must have 200px width (200px X 3 divs = 600px).

That way , you make sure that they fit in one row.

Comment: What Tejas commented was wat I wanted. Thanks for your reaction. P.s. I didn't downvote it.

Comment: Well someone downvoted and then restored it back to zero. Anyway, by looking at tejaw answer, now I understand the "graphic" of what you were looking for.